# Pass data from Codeigniter controller to a div with ajax

Tags: html, jquery, view, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to do a simple script in which it is made ​​an ajax call to a controller and its result is printed inside a div.

AJAX

```
 $('#search-bar-button').click(function(){
       var search_data=$('#search-bar').val();         
       $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('search/ajax') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: "data="+search_data,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg) {                    
                $('#result').html(msg);
            }
       });             
       event.preventDefault();             
       //return false;          
  });
```

CONTROLLER AJAX FUNCTION /application/controller/search.php

```
 public function ajax()
     {
    //$this->load->library('filtri');

    $data=$this->input->post('search_data');
    echo "<p>result= ".$data."</p>";
     }
```

VIEW

```
   <div class="span7">
 <?php echo form_open('validation/ricerca'); ?>
      <?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'search-bar');?>
     <?php echo form_submit(array('value'=>'Search','id'=>'search-bar-button'));?>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
   </div>
  <div class="well" id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
public function ajax()
{
    //$this->load->library('filtri');
    $data   =   $this->input->post('data');
    echo "<p>result= ".$data."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data variable. You are reading 'search_data' instead of 'data'.
In your controller ajax function use $this->input->post('data').

Comment: I fixed this, but still give an empty result. It should print anyway <p>result =</p> but it doesn't happen. <div class="well" id="result"></div> is still empty